# Http call in Rest Api fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

i am using flow to create a folder in sharepoint document library and breaking the inheritance by using this .`removing permissions:_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('@{body('Create_new_folder')?['{FullPath}']}')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=true)`  it works perfectly. Now when i want to assign permissions for a particular group by using the below uri in http it fails. it gives a message the URI is not correct. I am passing the correct principal id and role assignment id

```
 adding permissions fails:   _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{documentlibraryname}/{foldername}')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=49,roledefid=1073741827)
```

what is wrong in this URI

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Looks like a cache problem . When i tried once again like this it worked

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('@{body('Create_new_folder')?['{FullPath}']}')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=49,roleDefId=1073741827)
```